# Creating a component from all components in a namespace

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an index.ts file that exports lots of icon components.  I want to do 2 things:

1. create a component that outputs all of these components with formatting
2. filter the list of components to be outputted

Here is an example of an icon component:

```
import * as React from "react";

function ArrowCircleLeftIcon(props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) {
  return <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" {...props}><path fillRule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm.707-10.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 000 1.414l3 3a1 1 0 001.414-1.414L9.414 11H13a1 1 0 100-2H9.414l1.293-1.293z" clipRule="evenodd" /></svg>;
}

export default ArrowCircleLeftIcon;
```

I have all exports in an index.ts file so I can import it.  I can output a list of just the names like this:

```
import React from "react";
import * as Icons from '../icons/index'

export const Hello: any = (props : any) => {

    let iconKeys = Object.keys(Icons);

    return iconKeys.map((componentName) => <li>{componentName}</li>)
}
```

But I can't figure out how I can actually output each component instead of just the name of it in a similar fashion.  If I could make an array with the actual output I could filter it but I am not sure how to do that.

How do I output all components inside `Icons` with a loop of some kind so new icons added in will automatically be output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codesandbox of this code would be better. I created one sandbox for this POC. Hope you got context from this.

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Comp1 = () => <>Hello1</>;
const Comp2 = () => <>Hello2</>;
const Comp3 = () => <>Hello3</>;
const Comp4 = () => <>Hello4</>;

const Icons = {
  comp1: Comp1,
  comp2: Comp2,
  comp3: Comp3,
  comp4: Comp4
};

export default function App() {
  let iconKeys = Object.values(Icons);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {iconKeys.map((Comp) => (
        <li>
          <Comp />
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fog-7m5dq?file=/src/App.js:0-569